# Remote App Authentication Error (Code:0x507)

Tags: windows, rdp

I'm trying to get RDP services running with Windows 2008 R2. I'm at a WINXP SP3 client that was modified to run RDP with NLA. When I start the client connect to the local DC and get an authentification error (Code 0x507).

I've already done the following:

• Server

- Setup to run as a standalone local "DC" to provide Terminal services to a single application.  Remote Desktop Session Host CAL License is running & operational, RD Gateway Manager w/ Local Server RAP & CAP running NLA & operational
- Server has NLA & temporary use of port 3389 (which is directly connected to and 
  accessible from the internet (I am planning to change the port to 443, but want to get the 
  current system running first).

• XP Client(s):
 RDP-Version on win xp clients is 6.1
 If  had SP2, then added SP3 and edited the registry settings to allow NLA, by:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then press ENTER.
2. In the navigation pane, locate and then click the following registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
3. In the details pane, right-click Security Packages, and then click Modify.
4. In the Value data box, type tspkg. Leave any data that is specific to other SSPs, and then click OK.
5. In the navigation pane, locate and then click the following registry subkey: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
6. In the details pane, right-click SecurityProviders, and then click Modify.
7. In the Value data box, type credssp.dll. Leave any data that is specific to other SSPs, and then click OK.
8. Exit Registry Editor.
9. Restart the computer.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (on XP SP3 connecting to Windows 7). I followed the instructions you copied from the KB article, however forgot (actually skipped) step 9. Did a **reboot** and it started working. Yay.